# How to test Data Structure Classes?

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

How should a data structure class be tested in Apex?

What I mean by data structure class is a class that has no methods, for example:

```
public class myResponse{
    public String status;
    public List<Component> components;

    public class Component{
        String type;
        String value;
    }

}
```

I would use such a class for deserializing JSONs into usable apex objects.
Is there any way to test them, since they don't have neither medhods nor custom constructors?

Comment: Your testing of such an object can be quite cursory. Honestly, it should be covered by the rest of your test suite if you're using it anywhere.

Comment: Only aiming to [Test Everything That Could Possibly Break](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestEverythingThatCouldPossiblyBreak) suggests that a test is not needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are no constructors coverage is not made on the properties:

Given this class:

```
public class myExample{


    public class innerA{
        public string valA;
        public string valB;
    }


}
```

and this test

```
@isTest
public class myExampleTest{

    public static testmethod void basicCOverage(){

        myExample tmp = New myExample();

        myExample.innerA tmpA = New myExample.innerA();


    }


}
```

You get this coverage:
[image]

**To Resolve**:

1. Add an empty Constructor to you class

However, I do not believe that it counts against your code coverage as 0 of 0 does not affect anything. So you should just be able to leave it be.

Comment: Boy your `AccountProfile` class sure needs some work on the test suite! Might be a good idea to crop that screenshot more closely.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Ha, I did. but the 0% was due to running this test. It reset all coverage lol

Comment: Figured as much. Last time I saw a question about how to test pod objects it got negged pretty hard, surprised this one hasn't received the same treatment. It's basically a duplicate of [this one](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137564/how-to-cover-dto-class-in-test-class).