# How to write test class for DTO

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

I have a DTO class where lots of inncer classes are defined like..if i am wiring

```
public OuterClass{
 innerClass1{
//variables declarations

}
 innerClass2{
//variables declarations

}
...
...
 innerClassn{
//variables declarations

}



}
```

Following Class is not able cover anything. Please suggest easiest way

```
@isTest
public class OuterClassTest {



    @isTest static void myUnitTest() {
        Test.starttest();

        Outerclass.innerclass1 innerClass1= new Outerclass.innerclass1();
        Outerclass.innerclass2 innerClass2= new Outerclass.innerclass2();
        ......
       Outerclass.innerclassn innerClassn= new Outerclass.innerclassn(); 


        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: How many lines is it saying are uncovered. If it says 0% of 0 lines you should be fine.

Comment: one of 540 lines

Answer (score 4):

You either have to access each property or add a constructor:

For example

```
public class outerClass{

    public class innerClass{

         public string aProperty;

    }


}
```

To test the above you would:

```
OuterClass.innerClass c = New outerClass.innerClass();
c.aProperty = 'my value';
```

**OR**

```
public class outerClass{

    public class innerClass{

         public string aProperty;

         public innerClass(){}

    }


}
```

To test the above you would:

```
OuterClass.innerClass c = New outerClass.innerClass();
```

Some related information:

[Unable to cover get set in apex test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144699/unable-to-cover-get-set-in-apex-test-class/144718#144718)

[How to test Data Structure Classes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138304/how-to-test-data-structure-classes/138313#138313)

Additionally, I believe a class with no methods and only properties does not count toward coverage. If it says 0% or 0 lines you are good. I do not recall the complete ramifications though so I would personally just set the values